# Как получить значение и индекс того элемента,который был изменен в dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Как получить значение и индекс того элемента,который был изменен в dataGridView
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: где получить? в какой момент получить? что дальше с этими значениями делать?

Comment: После того как изменили значение в какой-нибудь ячейке.

Comment: вариантов много: начиная от получения выделенной ячейки и потом проверки ее индексов, заканчивая подписыванием на событие окончания редактирования и определения какую ячейку редактировали.

Comment: @Grundy Можно ссылки дать